# DRF: problem with writing nested serializer with unique field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to add some *tags* to a *post* when creating it. They have a many to many relationship, and tag has a unique *name* field. But I get an *already exists* error.

Here is my setup:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    (...)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts')

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            try:
                tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tag_data['name'])
            except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)

            post.tags.add(tag)

        return post

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        (...)
```

Now when I post the following data to create a Post:

```
{
    (...),
    "tags": [{"name": "someExistentTag"}, {"name": "someTag"}]
}
```

`serializer.is_valid` is called prior to `create` and I get the following response:

```
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": [
                "tag with this name already exists."
            ]
        },
        {}
    ]
}
```

What is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first thing I got working; get *tags* away from *post* and validate them manually (which I'm not sure is done right). Yet I'd like to see a better solution.

```
class PostSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            self.tags = self.initial_data.get('tags', [])
            if 'tags' in self.initial_data:
                self.initial_data['tags'] = []

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = self.tags
        existing_tags = []
        new_tags_data = []
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            try:
                tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tag_data['name'])
            except KeyError:
                raise ValidationError("Field 'name' for tag is required.")
            except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                new_tags_data.append(tag_data)
            else:
                existing_tags.append(tag)

        new_tags_serializer = TagSerializer(data=new_tags_data, many=True)
        new_tags_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        validated_data.pop('tags')
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for tag_data in new_tags_data:
            tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
            post.tags.add(tag)

        for tag in existing_tags:
            post.tags.add(tag)

        return post
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).